# How can I use Process class in Arduino Yun to read some stream-data?

Tags: arduino-yun

Running shell command through `Bridge` in `Arduino Yun` through a `Process` let's say, `proc`, it gives result and we can read the result bytes using following piece of code.

```
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <Process.h>

void setup() {
  Bridge.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
}

void loop() {
    Process proc;
    proc.runShellCommand("ls /root/");
    while (proc.available() > 0)
        Serial.print((char)proc.read());
    Serial.println();
}
```

What if I have to access data from a blocking shell command as it gets updated like and `event`? Such as, some consumer that listens to `Kafka` or `Mosquitto` subscribed topic. Whenever that topic is updated/published with new data, the listener gets it.

How can I model such structure using `Arduino Yun` program using `Bridge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it quite easily.
Run that particular command with `nohup`, in that case, file with the name `nohup.out` would be created. then after that run a script that continuously monitors that `nohup.out` file in case of any change in the size of `nohup.out`, get the latest data and push that data to anywhere you want.